# Is "Wobani" an intentional anagram of "Obi-wan"?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, easter-egg

I've seen in a couple of places, most notable [here](http://www.slashfilm.com/rogue-one-easter-eggs/5/) that

> The name of the prison planet that Jyn is rescued on is called Wobani, which is an anagram for the name Obi-Wan.
> <sup>*-[Slashfilm.com](http://www.slashfilm.com/rogue-one-easter-eggs/5/) - **46 Rogue One Easter Eggs: How Many of These Did You Catch?** Posted on Thursday, December 22nd, 2016 by Peter Sciretta*</sup>

**Is this an *intentional* anagram?**

Is there canonical confirmation that this was intended, or just a simple coincidence?

Comment: There's zero chance it was a coincidence.

Comment: I would not say a zero chance, but I would say it is higher than epsilon.

Comment: I don't necessarily doubt that it is a coincidence, however I'm yet to see the actual proof.

Comment: **I will be accepting my own self-answer on this one, however, if you feel that you have a better answer, feel free to post it and I will gladly consider changing.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Pablo Hidalgo sort-of confirmed this.**

I recently asked **Pablo hidalgo** (twice) on twitter about this, and [got a response](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/820139702267170820):

> I hadn't noticed until someone pointed it out; I don't know. All I see is a brand name of Greek yogurt.
> <sup>*[Hidalgo, Twitter, 2017-01-17.](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/820139702267170820)*</sup>

This is only a sort-of confirmation, as it doesn't say whether it *was* intentional or not, just that Pablo found out the connection after the fact. He also doesn't really seem to think it *is* a strong connection, given that the name "Wobani" sounds more like a greek yoghurt brand, **[Chobani](http://www.chobani.com.au/)**

[image: Image capture of twitter conversation between "Mooz" and Pablo Hidalgo, depicting Pablo's lack of knowledge of the name "Wobani" being an intentional anagram of "Obi-Wan".]

Comment: +2 for research effort but -1 for not actually getting an answer.

Comment: I'll never look at [Chobani](http://cdn.chobani.com/prod/chobani.com/img/display/fob/fob-low-fat-strawberry-banana-53oz.png) the same way again

Comment: **Note:** you may not see the tweets anymore because Pablo Hidalgo has done a cleanup of his account.

Comment: ooof - if a Pablo Hidalgo answer falls in the forest, is it still canon?